# Making grid layout responsive to display 1 and 2 columns on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

**NOTE: not a duplicated because the order of columns and rows is different than in the normal ways and specifically for mobile devices**

I am trying to display this grid layout on mobile devices in the following order:

1. first row: header (1 column using full width)
2. second row: main (1 column using full width)
3. third row: aside (1 column using full width)
4. **fourth row: alerts and weather (2 column using 50% width each)**
5. **fifth row: categories and about (2 column using 50% width each)**
6. sixth row: footer (1 column using full width)

First of all I am wondering if that is possible because I cannot make it work.

I can make it display 1 column per row on mobile devices. But to display this way in this order is a real pain for me. And I have been trying different solutions for 3 days without success.

Here is the HTML code of the layout

```
<div class="angry-grid">
  <header>header here</header>
  <main>main here</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <section id="alerts">alerts here</section>
  <section id="weather">weather here</section>
  <section id="categories">categories here</section>
  <section id="about">about us here</section>
  <footer>footer here</footer>
</div>
```

Representative image of what I want to achieve
[image: Representative image of what I want to achieve]

And here is the CSS where the problem is

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.angry-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "main main main aside"
    "alerts weather categories about"
    "footer footer footer footer";
  gap: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: #779999;
  grid-area: header;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  background-color: #8dd9b5;
  grid-area: main;
}
aside {
  background-color: #dd9b95;
  grid-area: aside;
}
#alerts {
  background-color: #ae69d5;
  grid-area: alerts;
  height: 200px;
}
#weather {
  background-color: #b5e5eb;
  grid-area: weather;
  height: 200px;
}
#categories {
  background-color: #6e7c57;
  grid-area: categories;
  height: 200px;
}
#about {
  background-color: #b5ba58;
  grid-area: about;
  height: 200px;
}
footer {
  background-color: #bdfb59;
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .angry-grid {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "aside" "alerts weather" "categories about" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 50% 50% 1fr;
  }
}
```

I am almost giving up and start creating a web design with old 1995 html tables ;)

Comment: And why the vote down? Because you are too pro for so easy questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grid-template-areas` are off.

Try these:

```
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "main main"
    "aside aside"
    "alerts weather"
    "categories about"
    "footer footer ";
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.angry-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "main main"
    "aside aside"
    "alerts weather"
    "categories about"
    "footer footer ";
  gap: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: #779999;
  grid-area: header;
  height: 50px;
}
main {
  background-color: #8dd9b5;
  grid-area: main;
}
aside {
  background-color: #dd9b95;
  grid-area: aside;
}
#alerts {
  background-color: #ae69d5;
  grid-area: alerts;
  height: 200px;
}
#weather {
  background-color: #b5e5eb;
  grid-area: weather;
  height: 200px;
}
#categories {
  background-color: #6e7c57;
  grid-area: categories;
  height: 200px;
}
#about {
  background-color: #b5ba58;
  grid-area: about;
  height: 200px;
}
footer {
  background-color: #bdfb59;
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .angry-grid {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "aside" "alerts weather" "categories about" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 50% 50% 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="angry-grid">
  <header>header here</header>
  <main>main here</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <aside id="alerts">alerts here</aside>
  <aside id="weather">weather here</aside>
  <aside id="categories">categories here</aside>
  <aside id="about">about us here</aside>
  <footer>footer here</footer>
</div>
```

## Edit

Try the [`grid-template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template?retiredLocale=de) shorthand syntax

```
      grid-template:
        "header header" min-content
        "main main" 1fr
        "aside aside" min-content
        "alerts weather" min-content
        "categories about" min-content
        "footer footer" min-content
        / 1fr 1fr;
```

That way you are better able to maintain a relationship between the template areas, columns and rows.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.angry-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "header header" min-content
    "main main" 1fr
    "aside aside" min-content
    "alerts weather" min-content
    "categories about" min-content
    "footer footer" min-content
    / 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: #779999;
  grid-area: header;
  min-height: 50px;
}
main {
  background-color: #8dd9b5;
  grid-area: main;
}
aside {
  background-color: #dd9b95;
  grid-area: aside;
}
#alerts {
  background-color: #ae69d5;
  grid-area: alerts;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#weather {
  background-color: #b5e5eb;
  grid-area: weather;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#categories {
  background-color: #6e7c57;
  grid-area: categories;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#about {
  background-color: #b5ba58;
  grid-area: about;
  min-height: 200px;
}
footer {
  background-color: #bdfb59;
  grid-area: footer;
  min-height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .angry-grid {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "aside" "alerts weather" "categories about" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 50% 50% 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="angry-grid">
  <header>header here</header>
  <main>main here</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <aside id="alerts">alerts here</aside>
  <aside id="weather">weather here</aside>
  <aside id="categories">categories here</aside>
  <aside id="about">about us here</aside>
  <footer>footer here</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: the columns are displayed in correct order but the rows are displayed in the wrong size in height with a big separation between the rows "alerts weather" and "categories about" so I think something is wrong in this part: grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
and grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 50% 50% 1fr; Can you please explain me how this size is set for this case scenario? because I don't understand that part

Comment: Thanks yunzen, It is working fine now. I am reading about the sized

Comment: Is it possible to set all to auto and then control the width and height individually in each element?